# Like case in MySQL without using OR or Union

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch all the employee's name which are started from A or B or C.
Also i don't want to use Union or OR conditions.

NOTE: I don't want these two solution 
CASE 1. (like '%A' or like'%B' or like '%C').
CASE 2. fetching separately and using union combining.

I have created sample data here [sample link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfa07a/2) Please find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Select * from employee where substring(emp_name, 1, 1) in ('A', 'B', 'C');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
select * from employee where emp_name REGEXP '^[a-c]'
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfa07a/9/0)**

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
select * from employee where emp_name REGEXP '^[abc]'
```

[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfa07a/21)

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can use `or`

```
select * from employee where emp_name REGEXP '^[a or b or c]'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfa07a/40)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Regular expression for this. The solution to your question is 
`select * from employee where emp_name REGEXP '^[ABC]`'

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfa07a/26)